# Best way to construct a "complex" data structure in Python

Tags: python, list, data-structures

I need to construct a tool that will be used to create field mappings (between tables) in the most automated manner possible.

Here is the deal: imagine a table being appended to other. (lets ignore field type, just for a second...)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE fooA(
id,
name,
type,
foo)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE otherFooTable(
idFoo,
nameFoo,
spam)
```

I am thinking to create a structure like this:

```
fieldMap = {'otherFooTable': [('idFoo','id'),('nameFoo','name'),('spam','foo')]}
```

I would be able to access this using (for example)

```
print fieldMap['tabelax'][0][1]
```

It´s not a very complex structure, but i can run into some problems using it? Is there any suggestions of how to handle this sort of issue? I need to store (for now) at least inputTable (i don´t want to repeat it for each field mapped), inputField,outputField. There is no reason to store outputTable, because that is always known beforehand.

Suggestions and past experiences are deeply appreciated.

PS: perhaps a formal structure (like a class) would be better?

Thanks

Comment: It's not obvious how your structure will be used while this is very important for its design. Also, please use self-descriptive names like `'table_from'`, `'table_to'`, `'id_in_table_from'` to make it more clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  what is tabelax?  How do the two tables relate?  What do you want the connection to be?  What do you mean by one table being appended to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little wrapper class for FooB's to mimic FooA's, but still retain their FooB-ishness.

```
from collections import namedtuple

# use namedtuple to define some simple classes (requires Py2.6 or later)
FooA = namedtuple('FooA', 'id name type foo')
FooB = namedtuple('FooB', 'idfoo namefoo spam')

# create a wrapper class for FooB's to look like a FooA
class FooAMimic(object):
    attrMap = dict(zip(FooA._fields, FooB._fields))
    # or if the fields aren't nicely ordered, declare this mapping explicitly
    #~ attrMap = { 'id' : 'idfoo', 'name' : 'namefoo', 'foo' : 'spam' }
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __getattr__(self, aname):
        ob = self.obj
        if aname in self.attrMap:
            return getattr(ob, self.attrMap[aname])
        elif  hasattr(ob, aname):
            return getattr(ob, aname)
        else:
            raise AttributeError("no such attribute " + aname)
    def __dir__(self):
        return sorted(set(dir(super(FooAMimic,self)) 
                          + dir(self.obj) 
                          + list(FooA._fields)))
```

Use it like this:

```
# make some objects, some FooA, some FooB
fa = FooA('a', 'b', 'c','d')
fb = FooB('xx', 'yy', 'zz')
fc = FooA('e', 'f', 'g','h')

# create list of items that are FooA's, or FooA lookalikes
coll = [fa, FooAMimic(fb), fc]

# access objects like FooA's, but notice that the wrapped FooB
# attributes are still available too
for f in sorted(coll, key=lambda k : k.id):
    print f.id, '=', 
    try:
        print f.namefoo, "(really a namefoo)"
    except AttributeError:
        print f.name
```

Prints:

```
a = b
e = f
xx = yy (really a namefoo)
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd honestly just take hints from (or use) [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) or [Django Models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/). These are tried and true data representation methods.

Comment: Hello geowa! Thank you for your hint. But i'm using this to program a few scripts using ArcObjects, from ESRI. I don't want to have a real big footprint to work, just to do a simple field mapping. Thank you though :D

Comment: And if you don't want to use an actual database on disk you could use SQLAlchemy with with sqlite memory engine. The tutorial here might be a good starting place: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/ormtutorial.html

Comment: @George: if i had to do this project, i would probably use a class-based approach *similar* to django

Comment: Why do you think ORM is good for such simple tasks? And how it will help to solve the problem of mapping from one to structure to other?

Comment: @Denis: well my main answer was to take hints from them. Make an object to represent the rows of a table. have a constructor to load the fields from the database taking some key as a parameter (like an id); then add save and delete methods. that's not a full ORM framework, but it uses the ideas, and makes using it simple, which is the point.

Answer (score 2):

Think about this

```
class Column( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, type_information=None ):
        self.name = name
        self.type_information = type_information
        self.pk = None
        self.fk_ref = None
    def fk( self, column ): 
        self.fk_ref = column

class Table( object ):
    def __init__( self, name, *columns ):
        self.name = name
        self.columns = dict( (c.name, c) for c in columns )
    def column( self, name ):
        return self.columns[ name ]

Table( "FOOA", Column( "id" ), Column( "name" ), Column( "type" ), Column( "foo" ) )

Table( "otherFooTable", Column( "idFoo" ), Column( "nameFoo" ), Column( "spam" ) )
```

It's not clear at all what you're tying to do or why, so this is as good as anything, since it seems to represent the information you actually have.

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid accessing your data through fixed numerical indexes as in `fieldMap['tabelax'][0][1]`. After a year of not looking at your code, it may take you (or others) a while to figure out what it all means in human terms (e.g. "the value of idFoo in table tabelax"). Also, if you ever need to change your data structure (e.g. add another field) then some/all your numerical indexes may need fixing. Your code becomes ossified when the risk of breaking the logic prevents you from modifying the data structure.

It is much better to use a class and use class (accessor) methods to access the data structure. That way, the code outside of your class can be preserved even if you need to change your data structure (inside the class) at some future date.